# How to import protobuf module

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto

With the `message.proto` file is being saved in `proto` folder:

[image]

I change the current working directory to the `proto` folder:

```
cd /test/proto
```

Then I am running `grpc_tools.protoc` to generate the protobuf Python module:

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I. --python_out=.  message.proto
```

The `message_pb2.py` is successfully generated:

[image]

The `script.py` is located one folder above and it contains:

```
from proto import message_pb2

message = message_pb2.Message(field_a = 'Monday')
print type(message)
```

When run the `script.py` successfully loads the `message_pb2` module and declares the `Message` instance:

```
<class 'message_pb2.Message'>
```

Now I want to pickle the message object appending two lines to the `script.py`:

```
import pickle
pickled = pickle.dumps(message)
```

This raises the `pickle.PicklingError` exception:

```
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'message_pb2.Message'>: it's not found as message_pb2.Message
```

## EDITED LATER

The reason why I've used a `pickle` module here is to describe another problem that happens when the `multiprocessing.queue` is used. The same`PicklingError` would occur when I try to place the `message` into multiprocessing `queue` using the `put` method:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
queue = Queue()
queue.put(message)
```

It results to the same error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'message_pb2.Message'>: import of module message_pb2 failed
```

How to solve this problem?

Interesting enough, that if I would place the generated `message_pb2` Python module in a same folder with the `script.py` the problem does not occur:

[image]

Modified `script.py`

```
import message_pb2

message = message_pb2.Message(field_a = 'Monday')
from multiprocessing import Queue
queue = Queue()
queue.put(message)
```

## SOLUTION:

Use `SerializeToString` method:

```
queue.put(message.SerializeToString())
msg = queue.get()
print msg.field_a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you are using Protobuf correctly. There's no point in pickling a Protobuf since the entire point of Protos is that they are serializable. Instead you should be using `SerializeToString` and `ParseFromString` as noted in the [Protobuf docs here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#parsing-and-serialization).

As they note there, you won't be able to actually read those strings because they're actually just a sequence of bytes that is using `str` for the sake of convenience.

EDIT: Looking into this more, Protobufs are not pickle-able, see here for more details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/VqWJ3BmQXVg